# Django Simple History - save_without_historical_record() does not work for me

Tags: python, django

I am struggling to make this work for 2 days.

I am trying to make a record without saving historical record with Django-Simple-History.

Here is the case. I have a model :

```
class Artikel(models.Model):
    treaty = models.ForeignKey(Treaty)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Heading, null=True, blank=True)
    artikel_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False,   choices=ARTIKEL_TYPE_CHOICES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

and here is my save() method

```
def save(self):
    self.save_without_historical_record()
```

Am I missing something crucial? Because I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/treaties/artikel/329/
 skip_history_when_saving
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error as you. The saved method was called recursively, so I added additional condition to the save method. Now my save method looks like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(self, 'skip_history_when_saving'):
        return self.save_without_historical_record(*args, **kwargs)
    return super(Artikel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope this works for you also.